# WebMatrix WebSecurity PasswordSalt

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, passwords, webmatrix, salt

I am using WebMatrix and have built a website based on the "StarterSite". In this starter site you get a nice basic layout - including registration, login, forgot password pages etc...

I've noticed that in the database that the "webpages_Membership" table has a column named "PasswordSalt". After creating a few new user accounts, this column always remains blank. So I'm assuming that no password salt (not even a default one) is in use.

Obviously this is not the best practice, however I cannot seem to find any documentation that tells me how to set or manage the password salt.

How can I set the password salt with the WebSecurity Helper?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

The above answer gives the impression that there is no salting applied when using `WebSecurity` `SimpleMembershipProvider`.

That is not true. Indeed the database salt field is not used, however this does not indicate that there is no **salt** generated when hashing the password.

In `WebSecurity`s `SimpleMembershipProvider` the PBKDF2 algo is used, the random salt is generated by the `StaticRandomNumberGenerator` and stored in the password field with the hash:

```cs
byte[] outputBytes = new byte[1 + SALT_SIZE + PBKDF2_SUBKEY_LENGTH];
Buffer.BlockCopy(salt, 0, outputBytes, 1, SALT_SIZE); 
Buffer.BlockCopy(subkey, 0, outputBytes, 1 + SALT_SIZE, PBKDF2_SUBKEY_LENGTH);
return Convert.ToBase64String(outputBytes);
```

Comment: Here's a post that goes into more detail: http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/200/The-SimpleMembershipProvider-Secure-Passwords-And-The-Crypto-Helper

Comment: As mentioned by [Mike Brind](https://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/200/the-simplemembershipprovider-secure-passwords-and-the-crypto-helper), Simple membershipProvider actualy use salted hash. But the salt is grounded in the hash value. The password can be hashed by **System.Web.Helpers.Crypto.HashPassword(password)** and can be compared with plain password string through **System.Web.Helpers.Crypto.VerifyHashedPassword(hashed, password)**

Answer (score 4):

As of the RTM release of WebMatrix/ASP.NET Web Pages, the salt feature/column is unused.

If you open up the Web Pages source, you'll see the db classes littered with references like

```
INSERT INTO [" + MembershipTableName + "] (UserId, [Password], PasswordSalt
```

...

```
VALUES (uid, hashedPassword,String.Empty /* salt column is unused */
```

*shortened for emphasis*

There are definately ways to override and implement this behavior, first being:

- override System.WebData.SimpleMembershipProvider.CreateAccount()

or

- extend with System.WebData.SimpleMembershipProvider.CreateAccountWithPasswordSalt()

not going to go into detail there though unless you request, as your usage of WebMatrix and a template suggests you probably don't wanna mess with rewriting a ton of your own C#/ASP code for this project.